# Integrate auriotouch

Tags: iphone

I need to integrate `aurioTouch` in another app. I have put all of his classes in my app, I have also changed is `didFinishLaunching` function to a normal void function, and removed `UIApplicationDelegate` tag from the header file.
In my app, I put this code:

```
aurioTouchAppDelegate *soundRecord = (aurioTouchAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[soundRecord startRecord];
```

I have also change the file in my app where this code is, to a mm file.

When I run this, I get this error:

```
2011-06-27 12:57:20.269 HomeSense[14996:40b] -[HomeSenseAppDelegate startRecord]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5846a30
2011-06-27 12:57:20.271 HomeSense[14996:40b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[HomeSenseAppDelegate startRecord]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5846a30'
```

Comment: I'm having a strong sense of deja vu here. Haven't we seen this question before?

Comment: I don't find an answer for this in this or another forum. Maybe I'm wrong...But you know a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to the fact that u didn't import the audio file **"buttonpress.caf"** in your ***Project->target->build phases-> copy bundle resources***. So, when your start record method gets called, the audio file isn't recognized as it is not in the project's target. I too had the same issue and it was driving me nuts for a long time, but then figured out this actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your HomeSenseAppDelegate class lacks a `-startRecord` method.

Comment: This method is in class `aurioTouchappDelegate`, and `soundRecord` is an instance of this method. But compiler thinks that the method is in `HomeSenseAppDelegate`. What is wrong?

Comment: It doesn't think that the method is in HomeSenseAppDelegate; it thinks that the method is *not* in HomeSenseAppDelegate. The error is complaining that you're sending `-startRecord` to an object of type HomeSenseAppDelegate, and that class doesn't have such a method. So, either you're sending that message to the wrong object or you've got a bad pointer somewhere in your app.

Comment: So maybe the problem is in this lines:
`aurioTouchAppDelegate *soundRecord = (aurioTouchAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[soundRecord startRecord];`

In the code I don't have another reference to this class.

Comment: What changes can I do in this lines?

Comment: Hard to say since you've only posted 2 lines of code, but I'd say it looks like your app delegate is not of the type you expect. You'll need to fix that. Look for the code that creates the app delegate.

Comment: My `aurioTouchAppDelegate.h` have this code:
...

inline double linearInterp(double valA, double valB, double fract)
{
 return valA + ((valB - valA) * fract);
}

@interface aurioTouchAppDelegate : NSObject `<EAGLViewDelegate>` {
...
}
...
----------
Im my app class, I have this:

`#import "aurioTouchAppDelegate.h"
...
- (void)viewDidLoad {
...
 aurioTouchAppDelegate *soundRecord = (aurioTouchAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 [soundRecord startRecord];
...
}`

In `aurioTouchAppDelegate.mm` I have a method called `(void)startrecord`...

I don't know what is wrong :(...

Comment: I have another delegate method `HomeSenseAppDelegate`, and I'm trying to use `aurioTouchAppDelegate`, and always when I try to call a method from `aurioTouchAppDelegate`, he references the `HomeSenseAppDelegate`, maybe the problem is in `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`?

I think that I need to set this delegate, but how I can do this?